# DevExpress - How to detect the device we are running on

Tags: devexpress, phonejs

I have downloaded the Devextreme package installed it and created a project in VS using their template.

I have created a simple 'hello world' dxview using iPad dimensions and one using iPhone dimensions.

Now I wish to load the correct view during first load, something like this:

```
if (runningOnTablet)  <-- THIS IS THE QUESTION!
   DevExtremeIPad.app.router.register(":view/:id", { view: "pgIPad", id: undefined });
else
   DevExtremeIPad.app.router.register(":view/:id", { view: "pgIPhone", id: undefined });
```

How do I go about writing views that look good on an iPad vs iPhone using the same code base (viewmodels etc)

I have created other sample views that look good on iPhone and therefore also on Android but if the user uses a tablet I wish to present different views!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [devices object](http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Core_Library/devices), e.g.:

```
var defaultView = DevExpress.devices.current().tablet ? "pgIPad" : "pgIPhone";
DevExtremeIPad.app.router.register(":view/:id", { view: defaultView , id: undefined });
```

Comment: Fab - that's what I was after!  Is what I am doing the correct thing?  I mean, depending on the device using different views?  Can't see an example from DevExpress regarding this...

Comment: It depends on the content posted in your views. Some views can be universal, like the login view with a couple of fields, some not. If a view has a large content, it is absolutely fine to make it tablet-specific.

Answer (score 0):

alternative method

if you have index.js in your project, look for something like that

```
var device = DevExpress.devices.current();
alert(device.platform) ;
```